# Flutter: How to change page transition based on previous page

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

I have a Flutter web app with a custom side navigation bar which is displayed on every page. So that I can always show the same side navigation bar while still keeping URL navigation I am using the `go_router` package with all of the pages in a `ShellRoute`.
Now I want to slide transition up to a navigation item below the current one and visa-verse. How can I achieve this?

Here's an over simplified version of my code

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        initialLocation: "/dash",
        routes: [
          ShellRoute(
            builder: (context, state, child) => SideNavBarPage(subPage: child),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: '/dash',
                builder: (context, state) => DashPage(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: '/other',
                builder: (context, state) => OtherPage(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: '/another',
                builder: (context, state) => AnotherPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SideNavBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget subPage;

  const SideNavBarPage({
    required this.subPage,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          CustomSideNavBar(
            items: [
              CustomSideNavBarItem(onTap: () => context.go("/dash")),
              CustomSideNavBarItem(onTap: () => context.go("/other")),
              CustomSideNavBarItem(onTap: () => context.go("/another")),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child: subPage),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For example: if I wanted to switch from `/another` to `/dash` I would want to transition down from top to bottom, whereas from `/dash` to `/other` I would want to slide up from bottom to top.

Comment: I think I've worked it out now. I'll upload my own answer once I've successfully implemented it.

Comment: The solution would also interest me. I saw your question but Didnt found a quick solution. The only way I could imagine about is, to make every child Widget (the content what you are changing) animated

Comment: I've uploaded my solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use go_router's `StatefulShellRoute` ([see an example here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart)).

Answer (score 0):

Use [auto_route: ^7.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) for navigation in flutter, it have [transitionBuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#tab-navigation) so that you can simply enable transition animation between pages.

Eg:

```
class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {                
@override                
Widget build(BuildContext context) {                
return AutoTabsRouter(                
// list of your tab routes                
// routes used here must be declared as children                
// routes of /dashboard                 
  routes: const [                
    UsersRoute(),                
    PostsRoute(),                
    SettingsRoute(),                
  ],          
  transitionBuilder: (context,child,animation)=> FadeTransition(                
          opacity: animation,                
          // the passed child is technically our animated selected-tab page                
          child: child,                
        ),       
  builder: (context, child) {                
    // obtain the scoped TabsRouter controller using context                
    final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);                
    // Here we're building our Scaffold inside of AutoTabsRouter                
    // to access the tabsRouter controller provided in this context                
    //                 
    //alterntivly you could use a global key                
    return Scaffold(                
        body: child,               
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(                
          currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,                
          onTap: (index) {                
            // here we switch between tabs                
            tabsRouter.setActiveIndex(index);                
          },                
          items: [                
            BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Users',...),                
            BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Posts',...),                
            BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Settings',...),                
          ],                
        ));                
  },                
);}}
```